# Hyper-V enable vt-x for guest in guest

Tags: hyper-v, vt-x

Is it possible to enable vt-x for a Hyper-V guest?

I need to run a 64 bit guest inside of a 64 bit guest.

Comment: Haven't tried, but this may help you
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can run Hyper-V within a guest as there is already a hypervisor running. (Pretty sure it tells you this if you try and install the hyper-v role).

I think your just going to have to run these other machines on the host server.

Comment: When Hyper-V is installed, the hypervisor is running all the time underneath the host OS, and only one thing can control the VT hardware at a time for stability.  The hypervisor blocks all other calls to the VT hardware. Hence you cannot enable/use VT-x for guest in guest

Comment: Maybe time to update the answer. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Answer (score 4):

Now you can; you got to run this in an admin powershell console, on a stopped vm.

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName <vm name> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)

Comment: Worked for me. In my case I needed to run a Ubuntu 18.04 as guest and inside it I installed VirtualBox so to be able to run 64 bit images (in my case minikube)